# How to get the value of isChecked property of a Checkbox in a data template

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

I have a class called People which has `STRING name` and `STRING ImgPath`.  I make a `LIST` `listOfPeople` which is the source of `icCheckBox`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="cBoxTemp">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding name}" MouseUp="CheckBox_MouseUp"/>                               
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

xaml

```
<ItemsControl Name="icCheckBox" Grid.Column="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource cBoxTemp}" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical"/>                                
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I would like to go through each time a checkbox is changed and populate a new list of the people that are checked.

```
private void CheckBox_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //  listOfSelectedPeople = new List<Person>();
        //  For Each (Person e in listOfPeople)
        //  if(cur.isChecked == true)
        //     ListofSelectedPeople.add(current);
        //  ... Once I have this List populated my program will run
    }
```

I cannot get the `isChecked` Property of the checkbox because it is a `datatemplate`.  How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a way to go. Using MouseUp is against MVVM.

You should bind to PropertyChanged event of each element of the list. When the propertyName is Checked, then your listening VM recreates the list of checked people for you.

```
class Person //Model
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string ImgPath {get;set;}
}

class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    readonly Person _person;

    public string Name {get {return _person.Name;}}
    public string ImgPath {get {return _person.ImgPath; }}

    public bool IsChecked {get;set;} //implement INPC here

    public PersonViewModel(Person person)
    {
        _person = person;
    }
}

class ParentViewModel
{
    IList<PersonViewModel> _people;

    public ParentViewModel(IList<PersonViewModel> people)
    {
         _people = people;
         foreach (var person in people)
         {
             person.PropertyChanged += PropertyChanged;
         }
    }

    void PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Recreate checked people list
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate?  The name never changes, just whether it isChecked or isn'tChecked.  Would I have to create my own isChecked property rather than the build in checkbox one?

Comment: Person is a model. You wrap it with ViewModel stuff (INPC). In VM there's a place to add additional properties (like IsChecked). At the end you have "master" view model which aggregates all items is the list. It binds to their events, in order to be informed about user toggling checkboxes.

Comment: I need the list to populate based on which people's "checkbox" is checked.  IsChecked is just a property that was created by the view model.  I need to check if the actual box is selected.

Comment: Bind it to checkbox's IsChecked property. Make binding two-way.

Comment: public bool IsChecked 
        {
            get { return IsChecked;}
            set { OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked"); }
        }

I bound IsChecked to checkbox IsChecked and notifies of updates.  What would I have to make my PropertyChanged( .....) {....}

Answer (score 0):

1. You still can get `IsChecked` property from Checkbox by cast sender to Checkbox.
2. However you should not add event handler in code behind for a `DataTemplate`.
3. The suggested way is to use DataBinding. Create a bool property for Person class and bind `IsChecked` to it in `DataTemplate`. In your bool property's setter, do the populating work.

Comment: Assuming Person class is a model, your 3rd advice is wrong. You should NEVER modify model to fit it into ViewModel.

Comment: That means your assumption is wrong. I assume person is the ViewModel.

Comment: This project is just to learn MVVM.  It honestly doesn't matter to me if the person is the model or view model.  The extra step is just helping me understand view models more in terms of putting the model in a wrapper with other properties

Comment: You're condtradicting yourself. If you want to learn MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) it is crucial to determine to which layer a class belongs to. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use EventToCommand and bind the Checked event to a command in your view model and send the current People object in the command parameter.

```
<CheckBox...>
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
          <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding PopulateCommad}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</CheckBox>
```

[EventToCommand reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)